# Istio VirtualService HTTPRewrite being ignored completely

Tags: url-rewriting, istio

I checked the logs of `istio-proxy` sidecar containers in the `api-service` deployment pods and in the default `istio-ingressgateway` deployment. The path remains the same, unwritten from ingressgateway to my service. I expect requests to look something like:

```
Client: 'GET mysite.com/api/some-resource/123/'
  ||
  ||
  VV
Ingressgateway: 'GET mysite.com/api/some-resource/123/'
  ||
  ||
  VV
VirtualService: rewrite.uri: /
  ||
  ||
  VV
api-service: 'GET mysite.com/some-resource/123/'
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-route-rules
spec:
  hosts:
    - mysite.com
  gateways:
    - istio-system/mysite-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /api
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: api-service.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 7000
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: web-experience.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
```

Comment: I have changed the `rewrite.uri` field to a multitude of random things and it just gets ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've found that the redirect **was actually** working, but the envoy sidecar was not reflecting this in its logs the way I expected.*

I inferred from [the docs](https://istio.io/v1.3/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute) that the envoy sidecar would log the rewritten path (Look in the **Description** of the `rewrite` **Field**):

> Rewrite will be performed before forwarding.

I checked the access logs for my web server running in my `api-service` deployment and found malformed requests: `GET //some-resource/123/` (from `/api/some-resource/123/`).

Turns out the extra `/` (from `rewrite.url: /`) was causing 404 errors. [A Github comment from an istio issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8076#issuecomment-467916427) presented a fix: whitespace.

**As the user warns, it's uncertain whether this behavior is intended.**

Comment: The semantics of rewrite seems to be: replace the part in `prefix` by the part in `rewrite`. So in `/api/some-resource/123/`, replace `/api` by `/', you get `//some-resource/123`. What you want is to replace `/api/` (notice the final slash) by `/`.

Comment: `Rewrite will be performed before forwarding` - I do not think it says something about what will be written in the logs.

Comment: As I said I inferred. In any case, what's the point of forwarding the request downstream after rewriting the uri, and then the sidecar logs the old, discarded uri...What's the point?

Comment: I guess the log in istio-ingressgateway shows the original URL. The log in api-service sidecar shows the rewritten URL. This way you get both URLs logged. I am not sure it was intentionally designed this way, do not see much harm though.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the log in the api-service sidecar shows the original URL. What you've said is the behavior i would expect based off the documentation, and why I am annoyed the sidecar is pointlessly logging the exact same thing as istio-ingressgateway. I almost thought my configuration was being ignored until I enabled and checked access logs for api-service's webserver. There, I discovered the issue with the double slashes.

Comment: Thank you @Will for mentioning this. I spent over an hour tearing my hair out, trying to figure out why my prefix rewriting wasn't working. The sidecar should really log the rewritten url, not the old one.